# Line Segment Intersection of a 3D Convex Non-Planar Polygon

Tags: algorithm, 3d, graph-theory, voronoi

I am attempting to find a decently optimal algorithm for determining whether or not a line segment intersects a 3D convex non-planar polygon. The best I can figure right now is to draw a line that splits the non-planar polygon in half, determines if the line segment lies to the right or left of the splitting line, then continue splitting until I can determine intersection. The reason behind it is so I can figure in which region of a 3d spherical voronoi diagram a given point resides. However, the time to find a solution can become depending on the float resolution of my line splits.

**Diagram**
[image: Spherical Voronoi Diagram]

**Non-Planar Polygon Example**

[image]

In this example, I would be drawing a line segment between the blue points and the center of the unit sphere (added after the voronoi calculation, they're not the points used to calculate the diagram). Then, I need to figure out which polygon that line segment intersects with in order to determine which region it resides in.

Comment: Do you have a polygon or a polyhedron?

Comment: @RazimanT.V. The shape included by the sphere is a polyhedron by definition. However, in my code, it is stored as a collection of polygons. I am only concerned with the individual polygon faces of the polyhedron in finding intersections. I believe the correct definition for the faces of the polyhedron in this scenario is 3D convex non-planar polygons

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be solved by coordinate geometry.

First, divide the polygon into triangles. For example if the polygon is ABCDE consider the triangles ABC, ACD and ADE. In your problem, the line segment intersects the polygon if and only if it intersects at least one triangle. We will check whether the line segment intersects a triangle in the following way.

Let the triangle be KLM and the line segment be UV. The equation of the plane containing KLM will be of the form ax+by+cz+d=0 and that of the line containing UV will be of the form (x-x_0)/e = (y-y_0)/f = (z-z_0)/g. By solving these equations simultaneously we can find the coordinates P=(x,y,z) of the intersection of the line and the plane.

Once P is found, we need to make sure that it lies on both UV and KLM. The former is true iff the sum of distances from P to U and V is equal to the length of UV. For the latter, check whether the areas of the triangles formed by P and the edges of KLM (that is PKL, PLM and PMK) add up to the area of KLM.

Comment: I'm not sure this works for a non-planar polygon. I can't think of how to simplify the geometry down to ax+by+cz+d=0 in this case. [See here](http://help.autodesk.com/cloudhelp/2015/ENU/MayaLT/images/GUID-752F96F6-89E4-4ACB-8E9D-B25034EB01FE.png) for a visual representation of a non-planar polygon.

Comment: Can you give the vertex coordinates of a sample non-planar polygon?

Comment: Here's an example of one of the polygons: 
       [[-0.01413831, -0.1588434 ,  0.98720255],
       [-0.28359024, -0.30261862,  0.90994426],
       [-0.24100966, -0.39396359,  0.88696507],
       [ 0.54257997, -0.8064585 ,  0.23501419],
       [ 0.6377325 , -0.4882386 ,  0.5957519 ],
       [ 0.39324987, -0.18387223,  0.90085823]]

Comment: But the surface of such a "non-planar polygon" is not uniquely defined from the vertices. As an example consider the polygon [A=(0,0,0), B=(1,0,0), C=(0,1,0), D=(0,0,1)] - there are multiple ways to "fill" inside the polygon.

Comment: Due to the nature of the search I'm implementing, how it's filled does not actually matter.

Comment: In that case just divide the polygon into triangles and perform the process in my answer. For example if the polygon is ABCDE you only need to look at triangles ABC, ACD, ADE.

Comment: @RazimanTV Can you elaborate on the steps to solve the plane and line equations simultaneously?